# Sigma fields and intervals on R

Tags: statistics, measure-theory

I've been looking at the following question and am having some trouble with parts,
basically you have to assume that a sigma field is generated by each of the following collections of subsets below and show why they are all equal.

A = {$(a,b)|a<b \in R$};

B = {$(a,\infty)|a\in R$};

C = {$(-\infty,a)|a\in R$};

D = {$[a,b)|a<b \in R$};

I've found that showing $\sigma (A) = \sigma(D)$ is quite easy as you just use the fact that you can write open internals i.t.o closed and vice versa. But what i cannot seem to get is why $\sigma (A) = \sigma(B)$ then $\sigma (B) = \sigma(C)$ and $\sigma (c) = \sigma(D)$

My initial though after seeing the problem was that you could simply use the fact that b>a and therefore if b could potentially be infinity and therefore showing $\sigma (A) = \sigma(B)$ is pretty trivial, only given that $b \in R$ am i correct in assuming that b could not actually ever be infinity and I have to find some other way of doing it? Should i rather use the fact that I am working with sigma fields and try to work it out that way? I am sorry if this is a completely idiotic question but it's quite late at night and I might be missing something very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sigma$-fields are closed under countable union and complements, so consequently also under countable intersection.

---

- If $a,b\in\mathbb R$ with $a<b$ then $(a,b)\in\sigma(B)$ because: $$(a,b)=(a,\infty)\cap[b,\infty)^{\complement}=(a,\infty)\cap\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(b-\frac1n,\infty\right)\right)^{\complement}$$
  This proves $A\subseteq\sigma(B)$ and consequently $\sigma(A)\subseteq\sigma(B)$.
- If $a\in\mathbb R$ then $(a,\infty)\in\sigma(C)$ because:$$(a,\infty)=(-\infty,a]^{\complement}=\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-\infty,a+\frac1n\right)\right)^{\complement}$$
  This proves $B\subseteq\sigma(C)$ and consequently $\sigma(B)\subseteq\sigma(C)$.
- If $a\in\mathbb R$ then $(-\infty,a)\in\sigma(D)$ because:$$(-\infty,a)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[-n,a)$$
  This proves $C\subseteq\sigma(D)$ and consequently $\sigma(C)\subseteq\sigma(D)$.
- If $a,b\in\mathbb R$ with $a<b$ then $[a,b)\in\sigma(A)$ because:$$[a,b)=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a-\frac1n,b\right)$$
  This proves $D\subseteq\sigma(A)$ and consequently $\sigma(D)\subseteq\sigma(A)$.